# How to retrieve species Id in NEAT to plot species over generations?

Tags: python, plot, evolutionary-algorithm, neat

I have done evolution of a population artificial creatures over 1000 generations and saved the checkpoint data.

So, now I would like to retrieve the species number that were produced in each generation and plot it. However, it seems like so difficult, even after trying several ways.

[image: From NEAT library, on how to retrieve species ID]

I have tried above method, heres the code:

```
import os
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import creature.plot2 as plot
import pybullet as p
import neat

local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = glob.glob(local_dir + "/*.pkl")[0]

# Load the saved genomes
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    Genomes = pickle.load(f)

# Initialize a list to store the number of species at each generation
num_species_over_generations = []

# Create a NEAT population and restore the checkpoint
pop=neat.Checkpointer.restore_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/neat-checkpoint-999")

# Iterate through the generations
for generation in Genomes:
    # Calculate the number of unique species in the current generation
    unique_species = set()
    
    for genome, _ in generation:
        individual_id = Genomes[0]  # Assuming genome.key represents the genome's ID/key
        species_id = pop.get_species_id(individual_id)
        unique_species.add(species_id)
    
    # Append the count of unique species to the list
    num_species_over_generations.append(len(unique_species))

# Now you have a list 'num_species_over_generations' containing the number of species at each generation

# Plot the number of species over generations
plt.plot(range(len(num_species_over_generations)), num_species_over_generations, marker='o')
plt.xlabel("Generation")
plt.ylabel("Number of Species")
plt.title("Number of Species Over Generations")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

but the error says that:
'Population' object has no attribute 'get_species_id'
File "/Users/sitiaisyahjaafar/Desktop/niche_evo_single_species/exp_data/radar4.py/20231003_110803/species-gen.py", line 29, in 
species_id = pop.get_species_id(individual_id)

I have set my population to be the checkpoint of population that have been run over 1000 generations that I saved. And during evolution, the data of reporting.StdOutReporter() were saved in the pop.

I really desperately need to see how the species changes through the generations in my experiment. Has someone ever tried it?